# Unsound definition of interior and boundary points of a submanifold of $\mathbb R^N$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold

In my lecture notes $M$ is said to be a $n$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^N$ if for all $p\in M$ there is a homeomorphism $\psi$ from an open neighborhood $\Omega_1\subseteq\mathbb R^N$ of $p$ onto an open subset $\Omega_2$ of $\mathbb R^N$ such that with $U:=\Omega_1\cap M$ either $$\psi(U)=\Omega_2\cap(\mathbb R^n\times\{0\})\tag1$$ ($0\in\mathbb R^{N-n}$) or $$\psi(U)=\Omega_2\cap(\mathbb H^n\times\{0\})\text{ and }\psi(p)\in\partial\mathbb H^n\times\{0\}\tag2.$$ The corresponding chart is $\phi:=\pi\circ\left.\psi\right|_U$, where $\pi$ is the projection of $\mathbb R^N$ onto the first $n$-components. If $(1)$ holds, then $p$ is an interior point; if $(2)$ holds, it is a boundary point.

I've read that we can assume that if $p$ is an interior point, then $\phi_k(p)>0$. Why? By the definition above we should only know that if $(2)$ doesn't hold, then $\phi_k(p)\ne0$.

**EDIT**: I get if $p$ is an interior point and $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, then $\tilde\Omega_2:=\Omega_2-(\psi(p)-\varepsilon)$ is open and $\tilde\psi:=\psi-(\psi(p)-\varepsilon)$ is again a diffeomorphism from $\Omega_1$ onto $\tilde\Omega_2$ with $\tilde\psi(x)=\varepsilon$. But if that's the argument, wouldn't we be able to modify $\psi$ such that it even satisfies $(2)$?

Comment: I don't follow problem (a): how does (2) imply (1)?

Comment: @ChrisCulter You're right, I made a silly mistake. Forget (a).

Comment: You can choose the chart $\psi$ such that all points have positive components. More precisely, if $\psi(U) \simeq \Omega_2 \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \times {0})$, then $\tilde{\psi}(U)$ which takes $U$ to $(\Omega_2 + (q_1,...,q_n)) \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \times {0})$ is also a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation What is $(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$? Maybe $\psi(p)=(q_1,\ldots,q_n,0)$? Please take note of my edit.

Comment: $(q_1,...,q_n,0)$ is any point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I was just trying to say that translation is a diffeomorphism. Also, no, you can't always modify $\psi$ so that it satisfies $(2)$. The reason is that if $p$ is an interior point, then $\psi(p)\in \psi(U)$, where $\psi(U)$ is open. In particular, if $\psi(p)\in \partial \mathbb{H}^n \times {0}$, say $\psi(p)=(0,p_1,...,p_n,0)$, we have $\psi(U) \ni q=(-\epsilon/2,p_1,...,p_n,0) \notin \mathbb{H}^n\times \{0\}$, where $\epsilon = dist(p,\partial U)$. This is a contradiction to $(2)$.
If it's still unclear, I can expand my comment to an answer.

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation I guess you're definining $\partial\mathbb H^n=\{0\}\times\mathbb R^{n-1}$. It's clear to me (since it's trivial) that $(-\varepsilon"/"2,u)\not\in\mathbb H^n$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ and $u\in\mathbb R^{n-1}$. The rest of your argument is not clear to me. If $p\in M$ is arbitrary, by definition, there is always a homeomorphism from an open neighborhood $\Omega_1$ of $p$ onto $\Omega_2:=\psi(\Omega_1)$. In particular, $\Omega_2$ is always open. Now, if you define $\varepsilon=d(p,\partial U)$, where $d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^n$ and $U:=\Omega_1\cap M$,

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation are you taking the boundary $\partial U$ with respect to the topology on $M$ or $\mathbb R^N$? It's clear to me that, since $\Omega_1$ is open, if we define $\varepsilon:=d(x,\partial\Omega_1)>0$ instead, then the open ball $B_\varepsilon(x)$ is contained in $\Omega_1$. I guess we need to choose $\varepsilon$ ensure that it is even contained in $\Omega_1\cap M$. If that's the case, it's  clear to me that this is a contradiction, since

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation $(-\varepsilon/2,u,0)\not\in\mathbb H^k\times\{0\}$, where $\psi(x)=(0,u,0)$, but $\psi(B_{\varepsilon})\subseteq\psi(\Omega_1\cap M)=\Omega_2\cap(\mathbb H^k\times\{0\})$, but at which point did we use that $p$ is an interior point? As I said before,$\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are always open.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. If $p$ is a border point, it does not lie in the interior of some neighborhood $U$. In fact, we need to differentiate between manifolds with borders and manifolds without border. I will write down an answer later.

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation It seems to me now that we can generally assume that a chart of a $k$-dimensional submanifold takes values in $B\cap\mathbb H^k$, where $B$ is the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^k$, and if it is an interior chart, it takes values in $B\cap\mathbb(H^k)^\circ$? If you know how we can show that, it would be great if you could provide an answer. (I need this specific result for this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3753368/47771.)